# Replace text in file with variable using sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I need to replace a string in a file by another string which is stored in a variable.
Now I know that

```
sed -i 's|sourceString|destinationString|g' myTextFile.txt
```

replaces a string but what if destination String was a combination of a hard coded string and a variable?

```
myString="this/is_an?Example=String"
sed -i 's|sourceString|${myString}destinationString|g' myTextFile.txt
```

The latter doesn't work, since `$myString` is not interpreted as a variable.

Comment: True. However the answer given here by Oli is clearer and less cryptic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bash doesn't interpret variables in single-quote strings. That's why that isn't working.

```
myString="this/is_an?Example=String"
sed -i "s|sourceString|${myString}destinationString|g" myTextFile.txt
```

Would work.

Or if you need the single-quote for another reason, you can just butt strings together and they'll be intepreted as one:

```
myString="this/is_an?Example=String"
sed -i 's|sourceString|'"$myString"'destinationString|g' myTextFile.txt
```